# confused about the exact workings of next() and __iter__()

Tags: python, iterator

When experimenting with implementing iterators I got confused about next(). I made a simple test script, where the iterator works as I would expect:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def prin(self):
        print self.name

class Some:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = list()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.SomeIter(self, len(self.data))
    def fill(self, obj):
        self.data.append(obj)
    def printMe(self):
        for entry in self:
            print entry.name

    class SomeIter:
        def __init__(self, some, end):
            self.index = 0
            self.end = end
            self.name = some.data[self.index].name
            self.data = some.data
        def next(self):
            if self.index == self.end:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                self.name = self.data[self.index].name
                self.index += 1
            return self

########################################################################


someX = Some()

obj1 = Object("A")
obj2 = Object("B")

someX.fill(obj1)
someX.fill(obj2)
someX.fill(obj2)

for obj in someX:
    print obj.name
```

I get "A B B" as output. That's all good. But then I also have an iterator for a tree class. The next()-method works basically the same. I first update the instance then return it. But in the case of the tree-iterator, the first element is skipped. Which makes sense to me, as I return self only after updating the instance. But why do I get different behavior in case of the above implementation, where the instance is being updated and only then being returned as well?

```
########################################################################
# RIGHT-HAND-CORNER-BOTTOM-UP-POST-ORDER-TRAVERSAL-ITERATOR
########################################################################
    class RBPIter:
        """!
        @brief Right hand corner initialised iterator, traverses tree bottom
                     up, right to left
        """
        def __init__(self, tree):
            self.current = tree.get_leaves(tree.root)[-1] # last leaf is right corner
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1 # right most index of sucs
            self.visited = list() # visisted nodes
            self.tree = tree
            self.label = self.current.label
########################################################################
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
########################################################################
        def begin(self):
            return self.tree.get_leaves(self.tree.root)[-1]
########################################################################
        def end(self):
            return self.tree.root
########################################################################
        def find_unvisited(self, node):
            """!
            @brief finds rightmost unvisited node transitively dominated by node
            """
            leaves = self.tree.get_leaves(self.tree.root)
            # loop through leaves from right to left, as leaves are listed
            # in order, thus rightmost list elememt is rightmost leaf
            for i in range(len(leaves)-1, -1, -1):
                # return the first leaf, that has not been visited yet
                if leaves[i] not in self.visited:
                    self.label = leaves[i].label
                    return leaves[i]
            # return None if all leaves have been visited
            return None
########################################################################
        def go_up(self, node):
            """!
            @brief sets self.current to pred of self.current,
                         appends current node to visited nodes, reassignes csi
            """
            self.visited.append(self.current)
            self.current = self.current.pred
            if self.current.sucs[0] not in self.visited:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current)
            self.label = self.current.label
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1
            self.visited.append(self.current)
########################################################################
        def next(self):
            """!
            @brief advances iterator
            """
            # if current node is a leaf, go to its predecessor
            if self.current.suc_count == 0 or self.current in self.visited:
                self.go_up(self.current)
            # if current node is not a leaf, find the next unvisited
            else:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current)
            if self.current == self.end():
                raise StopIteration
            return self
```

## Edit 1:

I compared the outputs of both iterators and they differ, the SomeIter puts out the first element 2 times:

```
next:  A
A
next:  A
B
next:  B
B
next:  B
```

the other iterator does not:

```
next:  a
s
next:  s
i
next:  i
r
next:  r
t
next:  t
t
next:  t
s
next:  s
e
next:  e
t
next:  t
```

otherwise "next: a" would occur 2 times

## Edit 2:

This really doesn't make any friggn' sense to me...

look these calls and the output:

```
someXIter = iter(someX)
print someXIter.next().name
print someXIter.next().name
print someXIter.next().name
```

output:

```
next:  A
A
next:  A
B
next:  B
B
```

with this code:

```
class SomeIter:
        def __init__(self, some, end):
            self.index = 0
            self.end = end
            self.name = some.data[self.index].name
            self.data = some.data
        def next(self):
            print "next: ", self.name
            if self.index == self.end:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                self.name = self.data[self.index].name
                self.index += 1
            return self
```

Why does this make no sense to me? Because, as next() is called the first time, it prints "next: A", then the instance is updated, and the return value of the function call is printed, which is again "A". Wah? Why is it not "B", as the return value should be the updated instance.

Comment: Can you perhaps minimize the amount of code to reproduce your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But the first block of code is already a minimized example... ? It contains executing code too. And the output is in my post as well. I don't understand how you want me to minimize it even more.

Comment: Why did you implement ```SomeIter``` as a class?

Comment: for one because I thought iterators need to be objects, second because I need several iterators in my actual program.

Comment: Are you confused about ```next``` or your implementation? ```next``` should return the next item and raise  ```StopIteration``` when exhausted.  Which version of Python?  And why aren't you using _new-style_ classes?

Comment: Don't even now what new-style classes are. python 2.7. And I am confused about next(). I have tried to explain that the output makes no sense to me. It returns the the first element, even though the instance gets updated to the second element before retrun self is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7

To be an iterator must implement the iterator protocol:

- defines `obj.__iter__` AND `obj.next`
- `obj.__iter__` must return `self`
- Once `StopIteration` has been raised, subsequent calls to `obj.next()` (`next(obj)`) must raise `StopIteration`

If a class only defines `__iter__` , `__iter__` must return an object that implements the iterator protocol.  If the items in the class are contained in a *Built-in Type* like a list, `__iter___` can simply return `iter(list)`.

I guess implicit in the whole concept is that an iterator has to keep track of where it is in the iteration.

If you want your object to be an iterator with different iteration sequences, you can define different methods to keep track of the iteration and advance to the next item then use those methods in `obj.next()`.

Trivial example:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Thing({})'.format(self.name)

class Some(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        # need something to keep track of the iteration sequence
        self.__index = None
        # type of iteration do you want to do
        self.direction = self.forward
    def __iter__(self):
        # reset the iteration
        self.__index = None
        return self
    def next(self):
        try:
            return self.direction()
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
    def forward(self):
        if self.__index is None:
            self.__index = -1
        self.__index += 1
        return self.data[self.__index]
    def reverse(self):
        if self.__index is None:
            self.__index = 0
        self.__index -= 1
        return self.data[self.__index]
```

Usage

```
>>> some = Some()
>>> some.data = [Thing('A'),Thing('B'),Thing('C'),Thing('D')]
>>> for thing in some:
    print thing,

A B C D
>>> some.direction = some.reverse
>>> for thing in some:
    print thing,

D C B A
>>>
```

So maybe just keep `next` simple and put the tree traversal logic in different methods. It might make it easier to test that logic.  And you can always add different behaviours:

```
    def odd_then_even(self):
        if self.__index is None:
            self.__index = -1
            self.__odd = True
        self.__index += 2
        try:
            return self.data[self.__index]
        except IndexError:
            if not self.__odd:
                raise IndexError
            self.__odd = False
            self.__index = 0
            return self.data[self.__index]

>>> some.direction = some.odd_then_even
>>> for thing in some:
    print thing,


B D A C
>>>
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how your *inner class* solution would work but one thing that looks amiss is that the `next` method of your iterator objects are returning self and it seems like `next` should return the next item in the sequence/collection.  When you iterate over a collection of things the iteration should *serve up* the individual things not a modified instance of the iterator object.